# How to supply LocalDateTime to a jpa/hibernate query?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm building a query in my @RepositoryRestResource

where the query looks like this:

```
@Query("Select DISTINCT comp from InsuranceCompany comp " +
            "LEFT JOIN comp.orders ord " +
            "wHERE ord.invoiced = false " +
            "and (:date is null or :date >= ord.completionTime)"
    )
public Page<InsuranceCompany> method(LocalDateTime date, Pageable pageable);
```

But it throws the following excpetion

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.LocalDateTime] for value '2020-02-14T15:50:24'
```

when I call the end point with:

```
GET /method?date=2020-02-14T15:50:24
```

Answer (score 3):

Mark it with `@DateTimeFormat` to have Spring converted it correctly:

```
public Page<InsuranceCompany> method(@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime date, 
                                     Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring by default cannot convert REST parameters to LocalDateTime. You need to provide information on the format of the date, at a parameter level with the @DateTimeFormat annotation, or globally using the DateTimeFormatterRegistrar.

This article explains the two alternatives: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1: Setting the date/time format globally for all Spring Boot App REST Endpoints

You can configure spring globally to use a certain date / date-time format for your REST endpoints. Suggesting that you use the default Jackson for handling JSON mapping, you can create a configuration class as follows where you set the formats:

```
@Configuration
public class DateTimeSerializationConfiguration implements Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = ISO_LOCAL_DATE;
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = ISO_DATE_TIME;
    private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER = ofPattern("HH:mm");

    @Bean
    public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<LocalDate>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalDate.parse(text, DATE_FORMATTER);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
                return DATE_FORMATTER.format(object);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Formatter<LocalDateTime> localDateTimeFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<LocalDateTime>() {
            @Override
            public LocalDateTime parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalDateTime.parse(text, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalDateTime object, Locale locale) {
                return DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(object);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Formatter<LocalTime> localTimeFormatter() {
        return new Formatter<LocalTime>() {
            @Override
            public LocalTime parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                return LocalTime.parse(text, TIME_FORMATTER);
            }

            @Override
            public String print(LocalTime object, Locale locale) {
                return TIME_FORMATTER.format(object);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.serializers(
            new LocalDateSerializer(DATE_FORMATTER),
            new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
            new LocalTimeSerializer(TIME_FORMATTER));
        jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.deserializers(
            new LocalDateDeserializer(DATE_FORMATTER),
            new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DATE_TIME_FORMATTER),
            new LocalTimeDeserializer(TIME_FORMATTER));
    }

}
```

Then, you can create controller methods like this:

```
@RestController
public class BookingController {

    private final YourService yourService;

    @Autowired
    public BookingController(YourService yourService) {
        this.yourService = yourService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/your/api/endpoint")
    public YourObject yourControllerMethod(@RequestParam LocalDate date, Pageable pageable) {
        return yourService.yourServiceMethod(date, pageable);
    }

    // Or: with LocalDateTime

    @GetMapping("/your/api/endpoint")
    public YourObject yourControllerMethod(@RequestParam LocalDateTime dateTime, Pageable pageable) {
        return yourService.yourServiceMethod(dateTime, pageable);
    }
}
```

---

### Option 2: Setting the date/time format for each REST Endpoint individually

If you prefer to set the format for each endpoint individually, you have to annotate the request parameter with `@DateTimeFormat` and specify the expected format. The example below shows different examples on how to accomplish this:

```
@RestController
public class BookingController {

    private final YourService yourService;

    @Autowired
    public BookingController(YourService yourService) {
        this.yourService = yourService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/your/api/endpoint")
    public YourObject yourControllerMethod(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate date, Pageable pageable) {
        return yourService.yourServiceMethod(date, pageable);
    }

    // Or: with LocalDateTime

    @GetMapping("/your/api/endpoint")
    public YourObject yourControllerMethod(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateTime, Pageable pageable) {
        return yourService.yourServiceMethod(dateTime, pageable);
    }

    // Or: with your custom pattern

    @GetMapping("/your/api/endpoint")
    public YourObject yourControllerMethod(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") LocalDate date, Pageable pageable) {
        return yourService.yourServiceMethod(date, pageable);
    }
}
```